# Substituting string into uint

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Let's say I have

```
uint uNum = 0xffffffff;
```

And I have,

```
string str = "07";
```

I want substitute the last “ff” with 07.
Basically this is the GOAL,

```
uint uNum = 0xffffff07;
//also equivalence to 4294967047 if converted to int64
```

How can this to be done?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `uint.Parse` to get the actual number, and combine it by first zeroing the last byte.

```cs
uNum = (uNum & 0xFFFFFF00) | uint.Parse(str, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```